# HTML and CSS images not appearing in their right place

Tags: html, css, image

I have a page in my site that has a table of employees. everything works fine except that the images don't appear in their right place. [here is a screenshot that explains the problem](http://s27.postimg.org/ir69em3pv/imgs.png).
and my code is here:

```
              <table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
     <td><figure style="text-align:centre;">
  <img STYLE="position:relative;"src="img/idimg.jpg" alt="idimage" width="110" height="110">
  <figcaption>Specialist's name<br/>ID<br/>Major <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Delete" /></br></br></br></figcaption>
</figure></td>
       <td><figure>
  <img src="img/idimg.jpg" alt="idimage" width="110" height="110">
  <figcaption>Specialist's name<br/>ID<br/>Major <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Delete" /></br></br></br></figcaption>
</figure></td>      

  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td><figure>
  <img src="img/idimg.jpg" alt="idimage" width="110" height="110">
  <figcaption>Specialist's name<br/>ID<br/>Major <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Delete" /></br></br></br></figcaption>
</figure></td>
       <td><figure>
  <img src="img/idimg.jpg" alt="idimage" width="110" height="110">
  <figcaption>Specialist's name<br/>ID<br/>Major <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Delete" /></br></br></br></figcaption>
</figure></td>  

  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td><figure>
  <img src="img/idimg.jpg" alt="idimage" width="110" height="110">
  <figcaption>Specialist's name<br/>ID<br/>Major <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Delete" /></br></br></br></figcaption>
</figure></td>
      <td><figure>
  <img src="img/idimg.jpg" alt="idimage" width="110" height="110">
  <figcaption>Specialist's name<br/>ID<br/>Major <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Delete" /></br></br></br></figcaption>
</figure></td>      

  </tr>
</table>
```

might the problem be because of my page's layout? or just changing any of the image's properties would work?

this is my css:

```
tr{
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    outline: none;
    color:grey;

}




table {
  border-collapse: collapse;

}
table td, table th {
  border: 1px solid grey;
    border-top: 0;
}
table tr:first-child th {
  border-top: 0;
}
table tr:last-child td {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
table tr td:first-child,
table tr th:first-child {
  border-left: 0;
}
table tr td:last-child,
table tr th:last-child {
  border-right: 0;
}



.colwhite{border: 1px solid white;}
```

Comment: This is not something that can be solved with the information you've given. Can we see the css file?

Comment: We need to see your CSS and a demo of the problem.

Comment: `text-align:centre` should be `text-align:center`

Comment: Well you have typo's. For example: `centre` should be `center`.

Comment: There is no `</br>` tag, just `<br/>` or `<br>`

Comment: I pasted my css above.

Comment: i corrected the tag <br> but the problem is still not solved

Comment: I corrected the typos but still doesn't work :(

Comment: If my answer below helped you answer your question, please consider marking it as the accepted answer...thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The quick fix is to `text-align: left` your `figure`. You had a few typos that I cleaned up for you in the snippet below, as well as a few other adjustments (`padding-bottom` instead of several line breaks, etc.).

Also, it might help for you to review CSS selectors ([this is a good resource](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048)) rather than using `style` attributes - it makes it much easier to manage.

```css
tr {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  outline: none;
  color: grey;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-top: 0;
}
tr:first-child th {
  border-top: 0;
}
tr:last-child td {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
tr td:first-child,
tr th:first-child {
  border-left: 0;
}
tr td:last-child,
tr th:last-child {
  border-right: 0;
}
td {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
img.specialist {
  border: thin solid grey;
  height: 110px;
  width: 110px;
}
figure {
  text-align: left;
}
input {
  float: right;
  border-radius: 12px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <figure>
        <img class="specialist" src="http://st.depositphotos.com/1742172/1357/v/110/depositphotos_13572136-excited-person-cartoon.jpg" alt="idimage">
        <figcaption>Specialist's name
          <br/>ID
          <br/>Major
          <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Delete" />
        </figcaption>
      </figure>
    </td>
    <td>
      <figure>
        <img class="specialist" src="http://st.depositphotos.com/1742172/1357/v/110/depositphotos_13572136-excited-person-cartoon.jpg" alt="idimage">
        <figcaption>Specialist's name
          <br/>ID
          <br/>Major
          <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Delete" />
        </figcaption>
      </figure>
    </td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <figure>
        <img class="specialist" src="http://st.depositphotos.com/1742172/1357/v/110/depositphotos_13572136-excited-person-cartoon.jpg" alt="idimage">
        <figcaption>Specialist's name
          <br/>ID
          <br/>Major
          <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Delete" />
        </figcaption>
      </figure>
    </td>
    <td>
      <figure>
        <img class="specialist" src="http://st.depositphotos.com/1742172/1357/v/110/depositphotos_13572136-excited-person-cartoon.jpg" alt="idimage">
        <figcaption>Specialist's name
          <br/>ID
          <br/>Major
          <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Delete" />
        </figcaption>
      </figure>
    </td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <figure>
        <img class="specialist" src="http://st.depositphotos.com/1742172/1357/v/110/depositphotos_13572136-excited-person-cartoon.jpg" alt="idimage">
        <figcaption>Specialist's name
          <br/>ID
          <br/>Major
          <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Delete" />
        </figcaption>
      </figure>
    </td>
    <td>
      <figure>
        <img class="specialist" src="http://st.depositphotos.com/1742172/1357/v/110/depositphotos_13572136-excited-person-cartoon.jpg" alt="idimage">
        <figcaption>Specialist's name
          <br/>ID
          <br/>Major
          <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Delete" />
        </figcaption>
      </figure>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I see you added CSS to your question, but that pretty much just changed the font and borders, so my cleaned up version of your code should work fine with your CSS added

Comment: Still the image doesn't appear in its right place, can you see in the screenshot i uploaded above, when i select the page's content, there is a white square which is where the image is supposed to appear but unfortunately it appears in a different place over the  figurecaption

Comment: and for the img in the css you added, i have other images in my site like logo ... etc and i don't want to apply this style to them. is it okay to just use style="..." with every single image?

Comment: I added **style="border: thin solid grey;left:00px;top:00px; "** to every single image and now it's working fine. I know this solution doesn't seem professional at all but it's the only thing that worked. thank you

Comment: Yeah, `left:00px;top:00px;` is pretty ugly. I updated my answer and I think it is now how you desire it. I highly recommend not using `style` attributes on all of your images. Define a `class` for them (as I did in my updated snippet) and manage the styling changes that way.